# How to store (in a "smart" way) data sent periodically to my server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, storage

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.13 and I have to store and treat feed data that is sent periodically to my server. I would like to store that data in a proper way since it is planned that that data will be used for building and displaying a line chart. My issue is mostly related to storing data in the database by caring *system performance* (since data is sent to the server each 30 seconds and can be long more than 5000 characters) and by keeping *ease of data manipulation* (since data includes hash-array structures).

That is, at regular intervals, my server receives data (within a HTTP request query string) that Ruby on Rails recognizes as the following:

```
Parameters:
{
  "feed1"=>{
    "1"=>"A,35,text1.1,5",
    "2"=>"B,76,text1.2,-6",
    "3"=>"D,45,text1.3,-1",
    "4"=>"Z,48,text1.4,-10",
    "5"=>"G,26,text1.5,-999",
    "6"=>"Y,10,text1.6,-67",
    "7"=>"T,98,text1.7,45",
    "8"=>"N,04,text1.8,315", 
    "9"=>"E,37,text1.9,90"
  },
  "feed2"=>{
    "1"=>"T,53,text2.1,76",
    "2"=>"J,67,text2.2,85",
    "3"=>"O,54,text2.3,-967",
    "4"=>"D,85,text2.4,41",
    "5"=>"N,97,text2.5,99",
    "6"=>"P,32,text2.6,48",
    "7"=>"Z,87,text2.7,21",
    "8"=>"S,27,text2.8,3", 
    "9"=>"I,67,text2.9,0"
  },
  "..."=>{...}
}
```

I would like to store the above data in a "smart" way and treat that data in a efficient way so to be displayed in a line chart.

How can / should I make that? There are some prescription or advice?

For example:

- Should I create a database row for each incoming feed data request (each 30 seconds!)?
- Since I would like to display in a char the data related to the past 24 hours, how should I manage data over the time? deleting "old" values? updating those values? or what?
- In order to save performance and database memory I thought to use the [Rails serialization](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serialization.html) functionality. Should I proceed with serialization? or, what could be another solution?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each feed is a simple hash, I think the format that is becoming popular for such purpose is the Labeled Tab-Separated Values (LTSV). That is, a hash:

```
{"a" => "foo", "b" => "bar", "c" => "baz"}
```

will be recorded as a single line:

```
a:foo\tb:bar\bc:baz\n
```

In your case, you can add the `"time"` attribute to each feed like this:

```
{
  "time"=>2013-07-21 02:24:01 +0900,
  "1"=>"A,35,text1.1,5",
  "2"=>"B,76,text1.2,-6",
  "3"=>"D,45,text1.3,-1",
  "4"=>"Z,48,text1.4,-10",
  "5"=>"G,26,text1.5,-999",
  "6"=>"Y,10,text1.6,-67",
  "7"=>"T,98,text1.7,45",
  "8"=>"N,04,text1.8,315", 
  "9"=>"E,37,text1.9,90"
},
...
```

and store that in LTSV. The code for encoding and decoding to/from LTSV is simple:

```
class Hash
  def to_ltsv
    map{|k, v| "#{k}:#{v.to_s.tr("\t", " ")}"}.join("\t")
  end
end

class String
  def parse_ltsv; Hash[chomp.split("\t").map{|f| f.split(":", 2)}] end
end
```

And since it is recorded as a text file, it is faster than using a database software.

Comment: Are you saying to store data in a text file (and not in the database)? If so the problem can be that I have to create tons of files on the server since mentioned feed data can relates to specific objects.

Comment: You can do it on a single file or two. Keep adding lines to a single file. If one file reaches the threshold (data for 12 hours), then erase the other file, and start adding lines to that file.

Comment: Come on, are you serious? Why not use Redis or Mongo and store this data in queryable way?